# GDAL tiling DTED (dt2) dataset as gdal2tiles for 3D Maps

Tags: gdal, dem, json, tile-map-service, gdal2tiles

i am searching some webgl technologies to create 3d map with digital elevation data. for web tech. i have found ReadyMap SDK to create 3d map from TMS...

in ReadyMap for elevation data it uses sth below to create a json data from tile which consists of tifs.

```
map.addElevationLayer(new ReadyMap.TMSElevationLayer({
            name: "Elevation",
            url: "http://readymap.org/readymap/tiles/1.0.0/9",
            args: "json=true",
            tmsType: "google"
        }));
```

in TMS mechanism one tile scheme is sth like this:

tms scheme : 10/294/752.jpg

in google scheme : 10/294/271.jpg

and for elevation data ReadyMap uses tiles as below:

http://readymap.org/readymap/tiles/1.0.0/9/7/157/94.json?json=true

i think in above link in zoom 7, folder name 157 and tile name 94 is both jpg and json format . jpg formats for tiles is in other storage or server....

and my question is that for creating digital elevation how can i tile my dted files like TMS scheme for creating digital elevation data? can i tile dted 2 with gdal2tiles or sth?